# smtp error Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, smtp

I am trying to send an email from a c# windows application. I am using smtp.office365.com. I'm getting the following error message:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I am doing this on a windows server 2012.

Find below the code i am using:

```
        try
        {

            smtp= new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
            message = new MailMessage();

            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("office365mailid", "xxxx");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("toaddress"));
            message.Subject = "Test mail";
            message.From = new MailAddress("my office 365 mailbox address");
            message.Body = "Test";

            smtp.Send(message);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            message.Dispose();
            smtp.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Just a tip: Instead of a try with an empty catch for just eventually dispose the `SmtpClient` and the `MailMessage` , use the `using` statement

Comment: No one has an idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that the connection to the SMTP server has been established, but it has been interrupted by it for several possible reasons.

Here are some reasons:

1. If you call the SMTP server from the IP address given by the ISP, you are probably in the public PBL (Policy Block List) and many SMPT servers actively disconnect the connection if the call comes from such an IP address.
   This is a common practice for spam protection from home computers.

You can see more here: The Policy Block List
https://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/

2. The host from which the email is sent must have the "DNS PTR resource record" correctly set. For "message.From", the host of the email must be the same as in the DNS PTR resource record, otherwise some SMTP servers will terminate the connection or issue a 554 error code.
   "How to Fix the 554 Invalid PTR Resource Record Error?"
   https://hoststud.com/resources/how-to-fix-the-554-invalid-ptr-resource-record-error.670/
3. "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead."
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0#remarks

MailKit: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit